# quick pathfinding algorithm for lot of objects

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, path-finding

i have lots of moving objects(maximum of 1000 objects) that each one needs to do pathfinding to maybe maximum 100 fixed locations(one object to one location at a time). What is the quickest pathfinding algorithm that best suit this? it doesn't have to be the shortest path, as long as the objects guaranteed to find the path is sufficient.

i have read the wikipedia about the A* but it says that the algorithm is slow.

if you have the code in actionscript 3 will help me alot

thx

Answer (score 1):

Here's an A* implementation in ActionScript. I haven't tried it, but it seems good enough to start with:

http://www.weekendcode.com/2009/12/a-pathfinding-in-actionscript-3-0/

If you want some more Path Finding help, you can check this tutorial at AI Depot:

http://ai-depot.com/articles/beginners-guide-to-pathfinding-algorithms/

Or at Amit's A* Page:

http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/